# printf sleep \n

Tags: c, printf

I was trying something when I saw this strange behavior. Can someone please explain it to me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("utkarsh");
    sleep(10);
    printf("dixit");
}
```

The expected output is print "utkarsh" then wait for 10 seconds, print "dixit" next to it.
But what I observed was that it waits for 10 seconds and the prints "utkarshdixit".

If I add a \n at end of utkarsh, it works as expected.

```
printf("utkarsh\n");
```

Could someone help me understand why am I seeing such behavior ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string? (in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: You need `#include <unistd.h>` for the `sleep()` call.

Answer (score 5):

you're encoutering buffering.

try to do

```
fflush(stdout);
```

in front of the sleep

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is buffering until you decide to write a `'\n'`.

You can use : `flush` to force to print

Answer (score 2):

```
Here, try this

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("utkarsh");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);
    printf("dixit");
}
```

There's buffering of the standard out going on. you have to explicitly flush it.

Answer (score 1):

There is buffering in stdout stream. Hence you need to flush once before sleep.

But when you used a '\n', the c run-time automatically flushes the stdout buffer for you. Hence you see this behaviour